# vscode code completion does not work when importing Nx homebrew library

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, nrwl-nx

Nx's import completion for homebrew library does not work

### Current Issue

I am currently trying to build an application with monorepo by Nx. I want each project to be able to import my own React component libraries.

My project consists of the following：

```
my-monorepo
  ├ apps
  │  └ react-project
  └ libs
     └ my-library
         ├ models
         ...
         └ components
```

my-library/package.json:

```
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./src/index.ts"
    },
    "./models": "./src/models/index.ts",
    "./components": "./src/components/index.ts"
  },
```

my-monorepo/tsconfig.base.json:

```
  paths: {
    "@my-monorepo/models": ["libs/my-library/models/index"],
    "@my-monorepo/components": ["libs/my-library/components/index"]
  }
```

The import alias itself is working according to the above settings. However, the modules under models cannot be completed in vsCode and must be entered manually.(On the other hand, code completion for React components under components was working.)

Perhaps the reason is that there are multiple modules exported in one file.
For instance,

my-library/models/function.ts:

```
export const func1 = ...
export const func2 = ...
```

and my-library/models/index.ts:.

```
export * from '. /function'
```

On the other hand, React components follow the convention of exporting only one component per file.

### Expected

How can I make code completion work on the caller side for modules in the named exported library?